# How can I avoid infinite loop when modifying textboxes (QLineEdit) that change related item info?

Tags: qt, textbox, infinite-loop

I have several fields in a widget, that each can affect the behavior of an item, and changing some of them will change others.

I read somewhere that the `editingFinished()` signal of a line edit is triggered only by user actions - and not by code changes... Is that true ?

```
connect(m_lineEdit1, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this, SLOT(m_lineEdit1Changed()));
connect(m_lineEdit2, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this, SLOT(m_lineEdit2Changed()));

connect(this, SIGNAL(someSignal()), this, SLOT(updateData()));

void m_lineEdit1Changed()
{
    changedata1();
    emit someSignal();
}

void m_lineEdit2Changed()
{
    changedata2();
    emit someSignal();
}

void updateData()
{
    m_lineEdit1.setText(fromdata);
    m_lineEdit2.setText(fromdata);
}
```

If I change `m_lineEdit1`, and update the entire widget (which changes, through code, `m_lineEdit2`), I hit a breakpoint in `m_lineEdit2Changed()`

This leads to an infinite loop of updates...

What can I do to get around it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocking signals is a bit of a sledgehammer of an approach. You can use a sentinel class to explicitly prevent recursion:

```
#define SENTINEL_STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define SENTINEL_TOSTRING(x) SENTINEL_STRINGIFY(x)
#define SENTINEL_AT __FILE__ ":" SENTINEL_TOSTRING(__LINE__)

class Sentinel {
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(Sentinel);
  static QMutex m_mutex;
  static QSet<QString> m_sentinels;
  QString const m_sentinel;
  bool const m_ok;
  static bool checkAndSet(const QString & sentinel) {
    QMutexLocker lock(&m_mutex);
    if (m_sentinels.contains(sentinel)) return false;
    m_sentinels.insert(sentinel);
    return true;
  }

public:
  explicit Sentinel(const char * sentinel) :
    m_sentinel(sentinel), m_ok(checkAndSet(m_sentinel)) {}
  ~Sentinel() { 
    if (!m_ok) return;
    QMutexLocker lock(&m_mutex);
    m_sentinels.remove(m_sentinel);
  }
  bool operator()() const { return m_ok; }
};
QMutex Sentinel::m_mutex;
QSet<QString> Sentinel::m_sentinels;

...
void Foo::m_lineEdit1Changed()
{
  Sentinel s(SENTINEL_AT);
  if (!s) return; // exit if this method is on the call stack
  ...
  changedata1();
  emit someSignal();
}
```

This is thread-safe and can be used from any thread.

Answer (score 1):

A technique to avoid this problem is to use the [QObject::blockSignals()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#blockSignals) function.

In your example you would do:

```
void updateData()
{
    m_lineEdit1.blockSignals(true);
    m_lineEdit1.setText(fromdata);
    m_lineEdit1.setText(fromdata);
    m_lineEdit1.blockSignals(false);
}
```

The blockSignals() call prevents the object sending any signals while you are changing the data in the line edit.

Comment: This is a very common technique that Qt introduced the `QSignalBlocker` class in 5.3, which overcomes some of the pitfalls of the manual way above.